# Unable to install pandas 0.23

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, pip

I need to install [BioBERT](https://github.com/dmis-lab/biobert) for my project and according to the requirements.txt document, I need to install **pandas version 0.23**. Using command prompt, I ran the following command: **pip install pandas==0.23**. However, I keep getting the following errors:

> Running setup.py install for pandas ... -    WARNING: Subprocess output does not appear to be encoded as cp1252

and then...

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b7c7z3mn\pandas\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b7c7z3mn\pandas\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-23blwwjr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pandas'
> cwd: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b7c7z3mn\pandas\

Then it tries to build wheel for pandas (setup.py) which results in another "Error":

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b7c7z3mn\pandas\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b7c7z3mn\pandas\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-23blwwjr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\pandas' Check the logs for full command output.

In case needed:
python version: 3.7.9
tensorflow version: 1.15.0
tensorflow-gpu version: 1.15.2

I would appreciate any help!

Regards

Comment: If the answer resolves your question, accept it by clicking on the tick mark under the answer's score.

Comment: @hoefling I already did, but keep getting the following warning: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: No, I meant the grey tick mark below the downvote arrow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdGo2.png You should be able to click on that to accept the answer; the tick mark will turn from grey to green then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might not be a wheel for Pandas 0.23.0 on Python 3.7 on Windows, and your box is lacking the tools necessary to compile it.

Try a nearby version, such as

```
pip install pandas==0.23.4
```

which [does have wheels available](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.23.4/#files).